# Sending definitions from the kernel to the subkernels: unnexpected differences for functions and variables

Tags: parallelization

I don't understand the strange behaviour below. Is this expected?

```
Clear[a];
b = a;
f[x_] = a x;
a = 1;

Block[ {a = 2}, {a, b, f[x]}]
ParallelEvaluate[ a = 2; {a, b, f[x]}] // First
```

Results:

```
{2, 2, 2 x}
{2, 2, x}
```

Only when executed in parallel, the value of `f[x]` does not depend on `a`. Variables, like `b` above, do not have this behaviour. Why?

I understand that this is related to how the functions definitions are sent to the subkernels. This seems to me to be a bug. Or am I wrong?

Another variation:

```
Clear[f, a]; 
f[x_] = a x; 
a = 1; 
Table[a = 2; f[x], {i, 1}]
a = 1;
ParallelTable[a = 2; f[x], {i, 1}]
```

Results:

```
{2 x}
{x}
```

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Wolfram and received the answer that the issue above was sent to the developers.

It is a small issue, but I would not expect this behaviour.

One can also check that the issue is not on how `f[x]` is processed in the kernel, since the very definition of `f[x]` in the subkernels is different, as it can be checked using `DownValues`.

```
ParallelEvaluate[DownValues[f]] // First 

(*{HoldPattern[f[x_]]:>x}*)
```